# How to concatenate values into string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have this SQL table:

```
user_skills 
==========================      
user_id | skill_id | value
   1    |    4     |   1
   1    |    5     |   1
   1    |    6     |   1
   1    |    7     |   1
   1    |    8     |   1
   2    |    4     |   1
   2    |    6     |   1
   4    |    4     |   1
   4    |    5     |   1
   5    |    8     |   1
```

Than, I have SQL query which returns me info about user.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT  u.*,
                        COUNT(a.user_id) AS jobs,
                        r.*
                FROM users u
                LEFT JOIN articles a
                    ON u.id = a.user_id
                LEFT JOIN rating r
                    ON r.user_id = u.id
                LEFT JOIN regions r1
                    ON r1.id = u.city
                WHERE   u.active = 1 AND
                        u.server_id IN (" . $server_id . ")
                GROUP BY (CASE WHEN a.user_id IS NULL THEN u.id ELSE a.user_id END)
                ORDER BY    u.points DESC,
                            jobs_done DESC,
                            u.id DESC
                LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $limit) . ", " . ($page * $limit));
```

Now, I need to select to each user their skills, or better, `skill_id`s. Ideally as a string separated by commas because we spoke about only 5 skill_id (4-8).

I tried:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT  u.*,
                        COUNT(a.user_id) AS jobs,
                        r.*,
                        CONCAT_WS(',', us.skill_id) AS skill_ids
                FROM users u
                LEFT JOIN articles a
                    ON u.id = a.user_id
                LEFT JOIN rating r
                    ON r.user_id = u.id
                LEFT JOIN regions r1
                    ON r1.id = u.city
                LEFT JOIN user_skills us
                    ON us.user_id = u.id AND skill_id IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
                WHERE   u.active = 1 AND
                        u.server_id IN (" . $server_id . ")
                GROUP BY (CASE WHEN a.user_id IS NULL THEN u.id ELSE a.user_id END)
                ORDER BY    u.points DESC,
                            jobs_done DESC,
                            u.id DESC
                LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $limit) . ", " . ($page * $limit));
```

But it returns me only the first `skill_id` from database, without concatenating.

When I tried to use `CONCAT_WS(',', us.skill_id) AS skill_ids`, result was comma and the first one skill_id (`, 4`).

Data in database are okay, `SUM(us.skill_id)` returns `30` for user with `id=4`.

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps the error lies elsewhere - or perhaps you're looking for GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks for your fast answer (it should be answer, not comment). It works fine. I thought it should be st. like "group_" or "_group", but in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html nothing with this name was. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems...

A) The function you want is `GROUP_CONCAT()`, which produces a CSV of values for the group. This query give you the skills list for each user:

```
select user_id, group_concat(skill_id) as skill_ids
from user_skills
group by user_id
```

B) A more major problem is your incorrect use of `GROUP BY`: For it to work as expected, you must list *every* column that is not an aggregate function, either using positional numbers or expressions.

Assuming users table has 6 columns and rating has 4:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    COUNT(a.user_id) AS jobs,
    r.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(us.skill_id) AS skill_ids
FROM ...
...
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6, 8,9,10,11,12 -- note 7 is missing
```

or you can list column expressions in the GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, ..., r.id, r.foo, ...
```

If you omit even one non- aggregate column, it won't work as expected. This peculiar behaviour is mysql only - every other database throws a syntax exception if you left one out.